# checkbox unchecked but value of the attached object attribute still true on server side

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

On the client side I have this declaration of a checkbox in `topologie.html`:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/bus/topologie}"
            th:object="${topologie}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
...
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{genererCle}"
            th:value="${genererCle}" class="genererCle" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" hidden="hidden" id="genererCle"
        name="genererCle"></button>
```

The .js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
    $(".genererCle").change(function() {
        $("#genererCle").click();
    });
...
}
```

On the server side it's working with a controller, TopologieController, in which I have defined a method :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bus/topologie")
public class TopologieController {
    private static final String VIEW_TOPOLOGIE = "topologie";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "genererCle" })
    public String genererCle(final Topologie topologie, final Model model)
        throws IOException {
        cadreService.genererCle(topologie);
        return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE;
    }
```

In the service classe `cadreService.java`:

```
public void genererCle(Topologie topologie) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if (topologie.getGenererCle()) {
```

On the first topologie.html display, the checkbox is unchecked. When the user checks it, it also works fine. But when I unchecked it, the client value is well updated :  on the js side, `$(".genererCle").is(':checked') = false` but in the `cadreService.java`, `topologie.getGenererCle()` is true.

What is my mistake?

Comment: $("#genererCle").trigger('click');

Comment: @Prs : I give it a try but it doesn't work better. As I've said the value on the client side seems to be good.